# Find multiple quoted strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Given this:

```
var str = "this.get('contact.firstname') + ' ' + this.get('contact.lastname')";
```

How do I get

```
['contact.firstname', 'contact.lastname'];
```

I've been trying a while and the latest unsuccessful regex attempt was

```
/get\('(.*)'\)/gi
```

Comment: Is the string always going to look exactly like that? It’s important to know *exactly* what you want to get each time. If it’s just singly-quoted strings as suggested by the title, `'(.*?)'` could work. On the other end of the spectrum, if it’s any string literal in arbitrary JavaScript, you’re going to need a full-blown JavaScript parser. Context is important!

Comment: `.*` finds the longest possible match. You seem to only get the text until the next `'`, so use `[^']*`.

Comment: @RyanO'Hara You are the only moderator who I never seen you here so far. Odd ..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is adding a `?` after `*`. So your pattern looks like this:

```
/get\('(.*?)'\)/gi
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJ4eP3/1)

Comment: Excellent!  I like regexes but I lose a lot of hair with them!

Answer (score 1):

Please check following

```
\'(\w+\.\w+)/g
```

You can play with it following url : 
https://regex101.com/r/cN9eX8/1

Please don't hesistate to ask more. Hope Helps!!!

Comment: You are right  I put backslash mistakenly. Thanks for correcting

Comment: Thanks, this works, but @shafizadeh's answer seems more flexible.